# External jQuery files don't seem to be executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Very new to HTML/jQuery and Stack itself, so bear with me.

My issue is that when I run my index.html file, it doesn't seem to be executing what I told it to do in my external .js file. I am trying to encorporate a simple accordian into a webpage.

The accordian itself appears in the webpage, but it's interactive features (i.e. its expansion) don't seem to work.

I have a niggling suspicion that this is a very simple issue to solve. However, here I am.

HTML file: index.html

CSS file: style.css

JS File: accordian.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Arial', serif;
}

.menu {
  width: 100% height: 65%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.menu>menu-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 65px;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Arial', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu>menu-content>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.NavBar {
  background-color: #000000;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.NavBar>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.NavBar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.NavBar>li>a:hover {
  color: #c5c5c5;
}

.banner>.banner-pic {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.about-section {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 40px 70px 40px 70px;
}

.about-section>p {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.toptips-section {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 40px 70px 40px 70px;
}

.toptips-section>p {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.events-section {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
   

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>RUNNERS WORLD</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slide.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="accordion.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <ul class="NavBar">
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#TopTips">Top Tips</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#Events">Events</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="banner">
    <img class="banner-pic" src="Images/banner4.jpeg"> </img>
  </div>
  <div class="about-section">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p> Welcome to the runners world page. It is here that you will find all essential information to get you started in running. You will find information on Events, Top Tips, along with several photos displaying the best techniques. I hope that you enjoy
      the website, and it acts as some inspiration to get you into running!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow">


  </div>

  <div class="toptips-section">
    <h1> Top Tips </h1>
    <p> These are my Top 5 Tips for getting into running, and getting on the road to a healthier lifestyle...</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Tip 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Tip 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Tip 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe is just a copy+paste error but you're missing the closing `})` from the `$(document).ready()` function

Answer (score 0):

I edited you question $(document).ready(function() {**});** was missing added it now your code is working I can't see any issue

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Arial', serif;
}

.menu {
  width: 100% height: 65%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.menu>menu-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 65px;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Arial', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu>menu-content>a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.NavBar {
  background-color: #000000;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.NavBar>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.NavBar>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.NavBar>li>a:hover {
  color: #c5c5c5;
}

.banner>.banner-pic {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.about-section {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 40px 70px 40px 70px;
}

.about-section>p {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.toptips-section {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 40px 70px 40px 70px;
}

.toptips-section>p {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.events-section {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
   

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>RUNNERS WORLD</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slide.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="accordion.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <ul class="NavBar">
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#TopTips">Top Tips</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#Events">Events</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="banner">
    <img class="banner-pic" src="Images/banner4.jpeg"> </img>
  </div>
  <div class="about-section">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p> Welcome to the runners world page. It is here that you will find all essential information to get you started in running. You will find information on Events, Top Tips, along with several photos displaying the best techniques. I hope that you enjoy
      the website, and it acts as some inspiration to get you into running!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow">


  </div>

  <div class="toptips-section">
    <h1> Top Tips </h1>
    <p> These are my Top 5 Tips for getting into running, and getting on the road to a healthier lifestyle...</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Tip 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Tip 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Tip 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Much appreciated.  Unfortunately, the accordian still isn't working for me when I run it out of Sublime text. However, it runs when I run the code snippet on Stack - strange.
Any suggestions? Must be something locally at my end.

Comment: do you use separate file for js css and html ?

Comment: Yeah, not sure whether that's good practice or not. Very new!

Comment: Keep separate files is a good practice check your imports for that js and css

Comment: By imports do you mean <script type="text/javascript" src="accordion.js"></script> ?

Comment: All files in same place ?

Comment: All files are beside eachother in a folder, yes. Very strange. I have tried several different browsers and all of them do nothing. I am running the .html folder from my file explorer. I'm not sure that that would make a difference?

Comment: What is happening when you open your html page in web browser ?

Comment: It loads up just fine (obviously without jQuery functionality).  In the we bar it has the path of where index.html is located on my PC - file:///User/Documents/Runner 1/index.html

Comment: Did you import jQuery ?

Comment: Yes, it’s at the top of the HTML file in <script> tags

Comment: banner4.jpeg ? do you have that

Comment: accordion.js do you have that